# how to find the index of certain object that matches the provided slug

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have a following data structure. It's a deep nested object.

From following data structure, i need to find the index of an object which has the slug as `level-1.1.3` so i can know if I am provided that slug, i have to add the items just inside that object children array. If not found any slug then add at the top level like `Another Level 1 B` object.

I tried the following way but i don't this this in efficient method and also could not find the index but found the whole object. The problem is, it goes to the else block as well so if i return null or something from else block then the included slug in an object won't get find if it's in too deep level.

```js
const data = [{
    title: "Level 1 A",
    slug: "level-1-A",
    url: "url",
    children: [{
      expanded: true,
      title: "Level 1.1",
      slug: "level-1.1",
    }]
  },
  {
    title: "Another Level 1 B",
    slug: "another-level-1-b",
    url: "url",
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: "Level 1 C",
    slug: "level-1-c",
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
      expanded: true,
      title: "Level 1.1",
      slug: "level-1.1",
      children: [{
        title: "Level 1.1.1",
        slug: "level-1.1.1",
        url: "/child",
        children: [{
          title: "Level 1.1.2",
          slug: "level-1.1.2",
          url: "/",
          children: [{
            title: "Level 1.1.3",
            slug: "level-1.1.3",
            url: "/"
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
];


function findIndex(data, slug) {
  var index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].slug === slug) {
      console.log('found in depth', data[i]);
      break;
    } else if (data[i].children && data[i].children.length > 0) {
      console.log('did not find in first level')
      findIndex(data[i].children, slug)
    } else {
      console.log('did not find at all')
    }
  }
}


findIndex(data, slug = "level-1.1.3")
```

Comment: Thanks for providing input and your attempt. Would you also be able to provide expected output for the `"level-1.1.3"` parameter? Your description "i have to add the items just inside that object children array. If not found any slug then add at the top level like Another Level 1 B object." doesn't really make sense to me. What items are you adding to the children array? What would adding to the top level look like?

Comment: for clear understanding of my use case, here is the one which i am trying to develop.https://codesandbox.io/s/vn1qr3wqm5. When you click on the, let's say `Level 1 A` item then you will see the add button which when clicked gives you an input field to input the value and after submitting the value will get added to the `Level 1 A` children array. This is what i want to achieve. For now for first level its working but not for nested level. I hope you understand.

Comment: @ggorlen Did you understand the use case? the concept is similar to adding folder in our browser(chrome) bookmark which is shown after clicking more button.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer to see the exact data structure you want to create. Your code loops infinitely when I click "add item exactly here," so the example wasn't too helpful, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array find and recursive in it to find slug (or anything else):

```js
var data = [
  {
    title: "Level 1 A",
    slug: "level-1-A",
    url: "url",
    children: [
      {
        expanded: true,
        title: "Level 1.1",
        slug: "level-1.1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Another Level 1 B",
    slug: "another-level-1-b",
    url: "url",
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: "Level 1 C",
    slug: "level-1-c",
    expanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        expanded: true,
        title: "Level 1.1",
        slug: "level-1.1",
        children: [
          {
            title: "Level 1.1.1",
            slug: "level-1.1.1",
            url: "/child",
            children: [
              {
                title: "Level 1.1.2",
                slug: "level-1.1.2",
                url: "/",
                children: [
                  { title: "Level 1.1.3", slug: "level-1.1.3", url: "/" }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function findslug(title){
  var slug = "";
  data.find(function f(current){
    if(current.title === title){
      slug = current.slug;
      return current;
    };
    if(current.children)
      return current.children.find(f);
  });
  return slug;
}

console.log(findslug("Level 1.1.3"));
console.log(findslug("Level 1 C"));
```

Comment: I am not finding slug but from the slug i want to find its position in an array so i can add the items in its children. I mean, if i find the position of object with the slug `level-1.1.3` then i can add the item to that object children array. This is what I am expecting.

Comment: Yes, you can reuse this code, and add object at the position matched (in `if(current.title === title) { //add code add object here ...};`